# Difference between generic function and function with Type parameter

Tags: c#, xml, generics, serialization

I just wondered what is the difference between using a function that takes a parameter of type `Type` (and some more parameter) and a generic function that just wants the type in `angle bracket`?

Idea behinde: I want to write a function that saves a type on ma filesystem as XML file. Since the XmlSerializer needs to have the type of object to serialize, I want to know: What is better?

```
private bool SerializeIt(object o, Type t, string filePath)
{
    bool result = false;
    try
    {
        if (File.Exists(filePath))
            File.Delete(filePath);

        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(t);
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            serializer.Serialize(fs, o);
        }
        result = true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        result = false;
        Debug.WriteLine(ex);
    }

    return result;
}

private bool SerializeIt<T>(T o, string filePath)
{
    bool result = false;
    try
    {
        if (File.Exists(filePath))
            File.Delete(filePath);

        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(o.GetType());
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            serializer.Serialize(fs, o);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        result = false;
        Debug.WriteLine(ex);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: You should change your `o` parameter to be a `T` instead of an `object`, then it might start to make sense.

Comment: In this case the generics are not adding anything to the method itself since you're not relying on its type at compile time. So I don't see the need for generics or the type parameter, you can just use `o.GetType()` in both cases as long as you do not need to handle nulls. If nulls are a problems then your generic version has an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first method will only work with the type `SomeData1`, since that is the type you specify. The other method works with any type passed through `T`.

You could solve the above issue with `o.GetType()` instead of `typeof(SomeData1)`. Still, the second method gives you the opportunity to use a base class as serialization base, which will clear out all properties in the deriving class.

Comment: the last sentence is what I searched for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Function `private bool SerializeIt(object o, Type t, string filePath)` is evaluated at runtime.
Where function `private bool SerializeIt<T>(T o, string filePath` is evaluated at compile time. That is inserting the specified type in IL code.

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of differencies. Firstly you can create constraints for generic parameters, e.g.:

```
private bool SerializeIt<T>(T o, string filePath) where T: ISomething
```

Secondly - free type inference for generic types.

```
private bool SerializeIt<T>(T o, string filePath)

Something something = new Something();
o.SerializeIt(something, ""); // dont need to pass type (can infer from first argument).
```

Thirdly - you work on concrete strong type, e.g.:

```
private bool SerializeIt<T>(T o, string filePath)
```

Generally it makes interface simpler and cleaner. You dont have to use loosely typed objects.